# Issue with getting a keyup function to get sum of input field values using plain Javascript

Tags: javascript, keyup

I'm working on a personal project and I've run into an issue that I haven't been able to solve.

Here is a function that generates new table rows into a table (with id of "tableData") when a button is clicked:

```
function addNewRow(){
  var tableEl = document.getElementById("tableData");
  var newLine = '<tr class="newEntry">';
  var classArray = ["classA", "classB", "classC", "classD"];

  for (var i = 0; i < classArray.length; i++){
    newLine += '<td><input class="' + classArray[i] + '"></td>';
  }
  newLine += '</tr>';
  tableEl.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", newLine);
}

document.getElementById("addRow").addEventListener("click", addNewRow, false);
//the element with id="addRow" is a button
```

I've simplified the code for the above function for the sake of readability as it's not the focus of the problem. When the button is clicked, a new row is added successfully.

The problematic part involves another function that takes the sum of the respective classes of each row and displays them in a div.

The goal is to get the sum of the values of all input fields with matching class names. For example, let's say I use the addNewRow function to get six rows. Then I want to have the div showing the sum of the values of all input fields with the class name of "classA"; the number in that div should be the sum of those six values, which gets updated as I type in the values or change the existing values in any of the input fields with class name of "ClassA".

```
function sumValues(divId, inputClass){
  var sumVal = document.getElementsByClassName(inputClass);
  var addedUp = 0;
  for (var j = 0; j < sumVal.length; j++){
    addedUp += Number(sumVal[j].value);
  }
  document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML = addedUp;
}
```

Here are a couple (out of several) failed attempts:

```
document.input.addEventListener("keyup", sumValues("genericDivId", "classA"), false);

document.getElementsByClassName("classA").onkeyup = function(){sumValues("genericDivId", "classA");}
```

Unfortunately, after scouring the web for a solution and failing to find one, I just added an event listener to a button that, when clicked, would update the div to show the sum of values. Also had to modify the sumValues function to take values from an array rather than accepting arguments.

My question is: How can I modify the code so that the sum value updates as I type in new values or change existing values using pure Javascript (vanilla JS)?

Answer (score 0):

You are very close, `document.getElementsByClassName()` returns an array of DOM objects, you need to set the `onkeyup` function for each and every element by looping through that array.

```
var classA = document.getElementsByClassName('classA'); // this is an array
classA.forEach(function(elem){ // loop through the array
  elem.onkeyup = function(){   // elem is a single element
    sumValues("genericDivId", "classA"); 
  }
}
```

Hopefully this fixes your issue

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the example below is not same with your situation, but you'll get the logic, easily. Anyway, do not hesitate to ask for more guide.

```js
document.getElementById("row_adder").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var t = document.getElementById("my_table");
  var r = t.insertRow(-1); // adds rows to bottom - change it to 0 for top
  var c = r.insertCell(0);
  c.innerHTML = "<input class='not_important_with_that_way' type='number' value='0' onchange='calculate_sum()'></input>";  
 });

function calculate_sum()  {
 var sum = ([].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("[type=number]"))).map(e=>parseFloat(e.value)).reduce((a, b) => a+b);
 document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = sum;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<p>
  <strong>Sum</strong>:<span id="sum">0</span>
</p> 
</div>
<button id="row_adder">
 Click me
</button>
<table id="my_table">
 
</table>



</body>
</html>
```